# Microsoft signing keys don't have endorsements

Tags: botframework

I was implementing authentication feature for Microsoft Bot as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-3.0)
. When observing the keys by exploring at https://login.botframework.com/v1/.well-known/keys, found some keys don't have endorsements with them.

*Sample key ID:* QMrt9-4Jn43rldid1E-hByyRC_Q

As per the document link provided above, we should reject any request which does not matches with the endorsements for the key, the token was signed with.

Can you please suggest with how to proceed next, as some of the valid request are signed with the keys that don't have endorsements with them...

Comment: I'll look into this with the dev team, and get back to you.

Comment: Hi Eric,
Any updates on the issue ?

Comment: Not yet.  I have asked the devs for some clarification, but have no updates yet.

Comment: Thank you for bringing this to our attention. We will be fixing this asap!

Comment: The fix for this has been deployed.

Comment: Please verify that this is working for you now.

Comment: Hi Eric, 
All looks good for now :)
Thanks...