# Microsoft signing keys don't have endorsements again

Tags: botframework

There seems to be an issue with Microsoft's Well known Keys published at https://login.botframework.com/v1/.well-known/keys.

Some keys don't have endorsements with them.

This issue was previously also reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50505166/microsoft-signing-keys-dont-have-endorsements) and fixed as well, but seems like it has resurfaced again.

Sample key ID: **9QFCOH2Wix3Ued-r16cLSPNbm6c**

Bot ID: **67e08555-4f99-482b-915c-2bfa2447c7c0**

Time Stamp (*approx*): 2019-01-16 05:23:24 (UTC)

As per the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) provided for bot authentication, we should reject any request which does not matches with the endorsements for the key, the token was signed with.

Can you please suggest with how to proceed next, as some of the valid request are signed with the keys that don't have endorsements with them...

[image: No Endorsement Public Key]

Comment: Thank you for raising this.  We will get this fixed ASAP!

Comment: This has been fixed.